# git clone - git clone error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Tags: openssl, git-clone

Yesterday I was trying to clone remote repository to my local system but was getting the above error, I tried to google for the solution but stack overflow answers did not help me. Today I found the solution so I am creating this by my own and you can find my answer in comments.

I tried to google for the the solution. I found many answers and article related to the same issue but those answers did not help me. I could not resolve the solution

Comment: Issue was I was trying to clone in mobile network(hotspot) So as the repo was big so it was failing. Today I tried the same in wify network and I am able to clone the same repo successfully